# Empty result when calling SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WebAPI using ASP.NET to expose some stored procedures I have implemented in a database. I am using ADO.NET to call the stored procedures.

I have a controller:

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("AuthSearch")]
    public AuthorizationResult GetAuthSearch(Guid? id, [FromUri]AuthorizationQuery Query)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String");
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_AUTH_SEARCH", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHNO", Query.AuthNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", Query.Status);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQDATE_BEGIN", Query.ReqDateBegin);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQDATE_END", Query.ReqDateEnd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQDATE_OP", Query.ReqDateOp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTDATE_BEGIN", Query.AuthDateBegin);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTDATE_END", Query.AuthDateEnd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTDATE_OP", Query.AuthDateOp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPDATE_BEGIN", Query.ExpDateBegin);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPDATE_END", Query.ExpDateEnd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPDATE_OP", Query.ExpDateOp);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REFPROV", Query.RefProv);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQPROV_FIRST", Query.ReqProvFirst);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQPROV_LAST", Query.ReqProvLast);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMB_FIRST", Query.MembFirst);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMB_LAST", Query.MembLast);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEMB_ID", Query.MembId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SORT_COLUMN", 1);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AuthSearchResult auth = null;
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                auth = new AuthSearchResult();
                auth.AuthNo = reader[0].ToString();

            }

            return auth;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AuthorizationResult auth = null;
            auth = new AuthorizationResult();
            auth.Descr = e.ToString();
            return auth;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And some model classes:

```
public class AuthorizationResult
{
    public string AuthNo { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public string MembId { get; set; }
    public string MembName { get; set; }
    public string MembSex { get; set; }
    public string MembDob { get; set; }
    public string MembHp { get; set; }
    public string ProvName { get; set; }
    public string AuthDate { get; set; }
    public string ReqDate { get; set; }

    public AuthorizationResult()
    {
        AuthNo = " ";
        Descr = " ";
        MembId = " ";
        MembName = " ";
        MembSex = " ";
        MembDob = " ";
        MembHp = " ";
        ProvName = " ";
        AuthDate = " ";
        ReqDate = " ";
    }
}

public class AuthorizationQuery
{
    public string AuthNo { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ReqDateBegin { get; set; }
    public string ReqDateEnd { get; set; }
    public string ReqDateOp { get; set; }
    public string AuthDateBegin { get; set; }
    public string AuthDateEnd { get; set; }
    public string AuthDateOp { get; set; }
    public string ExpDateBegin { get; set; }
    public string ExpDateEnd { get; set; }
    public string ExpDateOp { get; set; }
    public string RefProv { get; set; }
    public string ReqProvFirst { get; set; }
    public string ReqProvLast { get; set; }
    public string MembFirst { get; set; }
    public string MembLast { get; set; }
    public string MembId { get; set; }

    public AuthorizationQuery()
    {
        AuthNo = "";
        Status = "";
        ReqDateBegin = "";
        ReqDateEnd = "";
        ReqDateOp = "";
        AuthDateBegin = "";
        AuthDateEnd = "";
        AuthDateOp = "";
        ExpDateBegin = "";
        ExpDateEnd = "";
        ExpDateOp = "";
        RefProv = "";
        ReqProvFirst = "";
        ReqProvLast = "";
        MembFirst = "";
        MembLast = "";
        MembId = "";
    }
}
```

However when I run my project and navigate to

```
localhost/api/Auth/AuthSearch?id=GUID
```

I get an empty result set. If I run the same stored procedure in SQL Server using the same `GUID` value, I get a non empty result set.

I've used this same SP in a VB.NET web forms app without any issues.

I've ensured that the connection string is correct and I've double checked that the GUID I'm using is correct. What else am I missing?

When I run the same SP on SQL Server
[image: When I run the same Stored Procedure on SQLServer]

Comment: What is your result when you step through in the debugger? Are the AuthorizationResult objects being populated correctly?
 (As written, you'll only get an AuthNo populated in each AuthorizationResult, even if the program behaves as expected.)

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Khelvaster I'm only populating authno for debugging purposes.  if I try to populate the AuthorizationResult objects  using index values I get an index out of bounds exception. If I do it by column name I get an error as well. I will step through the debugger and update my question if I find anything

Comment: What is the type of @guid column in database? And is it giving any errors?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I stepped through with the debugger. No errors are returned. As for the `sp_` prefix, I did not write these stored procedures and I don't have access to change them. Interesting info though, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: I think the issue is related to " " vs. NULL.  You may want to instead use NULLABLE types that get passed to your SP, perhaps also check if the c# variables are NULL before adding them to the parameter collection.

Comment: I suggest you use SQL Profiler to capture what is _really_ being passed to the database. It's probably not what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps...

I'd of course change my strategy is to avoid using " ".

(The 'else' condition in place if you are forced to supply all parameters.)

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Query.AuthNo))
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHNO", Query.AuthNo);
else
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHNO", DBNull.Value);
```

By the way, strongly recommend you implement USING() since it takes care of DISPOSE and CLOSE, etc.

```
using (var ds = new DataSet())
{
  using (var con = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_AUTH_SEARCH", con))
    {
      using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {
        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
      }
    }
  }
  AuthorizationResult auth = null;
  auth = new AuthorizationResult();

  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    auth.AuthNo = dr[0].ToString();
  }

  return auth;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, however if I don't supply the parameter I receive a `SqlException` since `SP_Auth_Search` requires that all the parameters be provided. Would `else cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHNO", DBNull.Value);` be the correct approach?

Comment: That seems somewhat contradictory... Your SP defaults parms to NULL when not passed.  I'm not familiar with SP_Auth_Search... I did a goggle on it and nothing came up... if it's a setting you've applied "somewhere", I suggest you turn it off.. Again, that's because you've, within the SP, make your parameters optional by way of setting a default NULL value.

Comment: Then again I may be reading it wrong - I see that running it , you supply NULL's. Perhaps instead you can modify the SP so that the parameters default to NULL (if not already).

Comment: `SP_Auth_Search` is a custom stored procedure written by my boss. Unfortunately I don't have access to making any programmatic changes to the database

Comment: Got it - then pass NULL values rather than " ".

Comment: upvoted because your suggestions have helped, but unfortunately I'm still getting an empty result set. I will update the code in my question to reflect the changes you suggested

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
```

if your `@GUID` is of type `UniqueIdentifier`  if its a `varchar` or `nvarchar` then try this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", id.ToString().ToUpper());
```

to convert the type `GUID` to `String`

**Edit**

i noticed in your sp the `guid` is `upper case` and in code `guid` converts string to `lower case` maybe this was causing problem so try adding this `.ToUpper()` to make the string `uppercase`

Comment: My `@Guid` is of type `UnqiueIdentifier`. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I'm still getting an empty result set

Comment: and if you try .tostring then?

Comment: can you try adding the guid like  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", "B49FFBD7.........");`

Comment: Thanks, but the Guid is case insensitive. I tried hardcoding the GUID and  using `ToString().ToUpper()` but am still getting an empty dataset

Comment: its difficult to find problem without know about whats inside SP

Comment: SP shouldn't matter since I've already shown that it returns data in SQLServer. I've used this same SP in a VB.NET WebForms App and didnt encounter any issues...